Performing Habers Process with Tritium
I had an interesting thought when i saw the following problem in my textbook,

For a reversible gaseous reaction $\ce{N2 + 3H2 <=> 2NH3}$ at equilibrium, is some moles of $\ce{H2}$ are replaced by same number of moles of tritium, without affecting other parameters then what would be the effects?

One effect that i predicted would be radioactive ammonia, and that average molecular mass would increase, would their be any other interesting effects, has this experiment ever been done before?

The yield of synthesis will be lower, as more massive T generally reacts slower because of slower motion.

@Poutnik, thanks for the observation, would it have any effect on $K_p, K_c$?

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. //
Searching domains stackexchange.com, wikipedia.org and optionally libretexts.org is assumed as prerequisite before asking. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

See https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/10148760

@JonCuster Thanks for the reply


[OP] has this experiment ever been done before?

Yes.

Heung, L K. "Tritiated ammonia formation.", 1994. DOI: 10.2172/10148760

Lucas M. et.al., Evaluation of catalysts for decomposition of ammonia in hydrogen isotope purification systems, 2021, DOI: 10.1016/j.fusengdes.2021.112895



If the first citation is not available, the osti.gov link above gets you to their work.
